# How to center an icon in a extjs button?

Tags: html, css, extjs

I have a simple button, but I can't make the icon to be centered on it.

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    cls: 'startbutton'
}
```

css:

```
.startbutton { 
    background-image: url(Camera.png) !important;
}
```

This image is 72x72 pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think,you need [**background-position**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position):

```
.startbutton { 
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(Camera.png) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there reason you're not using standard things:

```
icon: '',
iconAlign: 'center'
```

Comment: @sha: FYI there was a potential problem identified with this post... http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1748742

Comment: iconAlign does not has a value 'center'. Ext JS 4.2.1.